# Отчёты в Ruby. Что используете для создания отчётов? Ruport не работает с Ruby 2.1, хотя заявлены требования 2.0 или старше

Tags: ruby

Возникла потребность генерировать отчёты на Ruby.
Нашёл gem ruport:

> Библиотека Ruport (Ruby reports) предназначена для лёгкой реализации отчётов и создания диаграмм на основе данных из БД или прямо из текстовых файлов CSV. Причём результаты можно сохранять в форматах PDF, HTML, CSV и TXT.

Но не работает. А версии Ruby 1.9 у класса String убрали метод `#each` а рупорт продолжает его использовать. Так что заявленная версия руби не соответствует действительности. Примеры с [гитхаба](https://github.com/ruport/ruport/tree/master/examples) не работают.

Устаноновлены:

```
ruby 2.1.10p492
ruport 1.7.1
```

Может есть рабочее решение для создания текстовых и PDF (а может и XLS) отчётов?
Prawn позволяет создавать отчёты только в PDF.

Comment: А при чём тут Rails? И чем не устраивает Prawn, если XLS необязателен?

Comment: Prawn позволяет создавать только PDF. Нужно и в текстовом формате создавать.

Comment: Похоже что автор в ветке `master` что-то починил. Попробуйте версию с гитхаба. Если не заведётся, значит придётся либо реставрировать самостоятельно, либо разрабатывать новое.

Answer (score 0):

Определил, что ошибка не в `ruport`, а в `gem pdf-writer-1.1.8`. ruport не сам генерирует PDF, а использует стороннюю библиотеку.

Гем `pdf-writer` не обновляется с 2008 года.

Буду думать как обойти это.